# Remover item de uma class Adapter

Tags: java, android-studio

Estou tentando remover o item da listview, porem quando eu vou testar o app não faz nada...
Minha class ProdutoAdapter:

```
public class ProdutoAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Carrinho_Item> {
    private Context context;
    private List<Carrinho_Item> item;

    public ProdutoAdapter(@NonNull Context context, @LayoutRes int resource, @NonNull List<Carrinho_Item> objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
        this.context = context;
        this.item = objects;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int pos, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_carrinho, parent, false);

        TextView txtCodigo = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.txtCodigoDoProduto);
        TextView txtDescricao = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.txtProduto);
        TextView txtCor = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.txtCor);
        TextView txtTamanho = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.txtTamanho);
        TextView txtQuantidade = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.txtQuantidade);

        txtCodigo.setText(""+item.get(pos).getCodigo());
        txtDescricao.setText(item.get(pos).getNome());
        txtCor.setText(""+item.get(pos).getCor());
        txtTamanho.setText(item.get(pos).getTamanho());
        txtQuantidade.setText(""+item.get(pos).getQuantidade());

        rowView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                item.remove(item.get(pos));
            }
        });

        return rowView;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Após a remoção do item (`item.remove(...)`) você deve notificar o adaptador de que houve uma mudança nos dados. Isso pode ser feito com o método [`notifyDatasetChanged`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged()).

Considere a possibilidade de utilizar o padrão `ViewHolder` para otimizar o desempenho da sua lista. Veja [este artigo](https://blog.alura.com.br/utilizando-o-padrao-viewholder/) sobre como fazê-lo.

Comment: Vlw mano, salvo ! Deu certo aqui

Comment: Ótimo! Não esqueça de marcar a resposta como solução.